# TFS command line on Ubuntu 14.04 without Eclipse

Tags: ubuntu, tfs

As the title says, my googling has failed me. Is it possible to get the TFS command line on ubuntu without installing eclipse and getting the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Download the TEE CLC (Command Line Client), which is packaged up as part of Team Explorer Everywhere.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785